# How to add cache feature in Spring Data JPA CRUDRepository

Tags: spring, hibernate, caching, jpa, jdbc

I want to add "Cacheable" annotation in findOne method, and evict the cache when delete or happen methods happened.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 13):

virsir, there is one more way if you use Spring Data JPA (using just interfaces). Here what I have done, genereic dao for similar structured entities:

```
public interface CachingDao<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<T> {

@Cacheable(value = "myCache")
T findOne(ID id);

@Cacheable(value = "myCache")
List<T> findAll();

@Cacheable(value = "myCache")
Page<T> findAll(Pageable pageable);

....

@CacheEvict(value = "myCache", allEntries = true)
<S extends T> S save(S entity);

....

@CacheEvict(value = "myCache", allEntries = true)
void delete(ID id);
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain why you use `@CacheEvict` for the method `save`??
Why wouldn't you use `@CachePut`? Wouldn't saving it update the Cache correctly, and thus not require `@Cacheable` to even run after a save (assuming the cache is still there ofcourse)

Comment: @seven nice! note that it is possible to annotate the `Repo` with `@CacheConfig` so the `cache` name will be outside of `CachingDao`

Comment: To build on @delver's comment: "Spring recommends that you only annotate concrete classes (and methods of concrete classes) with the @Cache* annotation, as opposed to annotating interfaces." See the source for more details -- http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html

Comment: Oddly Spring's own examples show using `@Cache*` annotations on interfaces ... 

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/master/jpa/example/src/main/java/example/springdata/jpa/caching/CachingUserRepository.java

Comment: Anyone know why you would evict all entires when saving or deleting a single record?

Comment: @seven - Is there a way to write some code to update this cache managed by spring? I want to update the cache in a jms consumer implementation.

Answer (score 9):

I think basically @seven's answer is correct, but with 2 missing points:

1. We cannot define a generic interface, I'm afraid we have to declare every concrete interface separately since annotation cannot be inherited and we need to have different cache names for each repository.
2. `save` and `delete` should be `CachePut`, and `findAll` should be both `Cacheable` and `CacheEvict`

   ```
   public interface CacheRepository extends CrudRepository<T, String> {

       @Cacheable("cacheName")
       T findOne(String name);

       @Cacheable("cacheName")
       @CacheEvict(value = "cacheName", allEntries = true)
       Iterable<T> findAll();

       @Override
       @CachePut("cacheName")
       T save(T entity);

       @Override
       @CacheEvict("cacheName")
       void delete(String name);
   }
   ```

[Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html)

Comment: I dont know why there is negative rating, but 1) is true and I guess that evic allentries is there because your cache may have as keys different values then PK, thus when modifiing record, you should specify what to evict - and if you have only PK, you dont know cache key, so you dont know which cache record invalidate

Answer (score 5):

I solved the this in the following way and its working fine

---

```
public interface BookRepositoryCustom {

    Book findOne(Long id);

}
```

---

```
public class BookRepositoryImpl extends SimpleJpaRepository<Book,Long> implements BookRepositoryCustom {

    @Inject
    public BookRepositoryImpl(EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(Book.class, entityManager);
    }

    @Cacheable(value = "books", key = "#id")
    public Book findOne(Long id) {
        return super.findOne(id);
    }

}
```

---

```
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book,Long>, BookRepositoryCustom {

}
```

Comment: I have many repositories, is there an easy way to implement this?

Comment: I am not aware of the other ways. I just know only this way.

Answer (score 2):

Try provide MyCRUDRepository (an interface and an implementation) as explained here: [Adding custom behaviour to all repositories](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories). Then you can override and add annotations for these methods:

```
findOne(ID id)
delete(T entity)
delete(Iterable<? extends T> entities)
deleteAll() 
delete(ID id)
```