# Is it possible to define generic interface and use Spring @CacheConfig?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-cache, spring-data-redis

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19708529/1211174) I tried to do the following

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface CacheableRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>
    extends JpaRepository<T, ID>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<T>,       PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID> {

    @Cacheable()
    T findOne(ID id);

    @Cacheable()
    List<T> findAll();

   @Cacheable()
   Page<T> findAll(Pageable pageable);

   @CacheEvict(allEntries = true)
   <S extends T> S save(S entity);

   @CacheEvict(allEntries = true)
   void delete(ID id);

}
```

Then use this interface to define the Used repository

```
 @CacheConfig(cacheNames={"uniqueCache"})
 public interface SomeObjectRepo extends    CacheableRepository<SomeObject, Long>  {

     @Cacheable(key = "someobject+#p0")
     List<SomeObject> findByType(Integer type);

    @Cacheable(key = "someobject+#p0")
    List<SomeObject> findByCategory(String field);

    @Cacheable(key="someobject+#p0.concat(#p1)")
    List<SomeObject> findByCategoryAndWizardType_id(String field,Integer id);

 }
```

### Works:

The cache above work for `findByType`,`findByCategory`,`findByCategoryAndWizardType_id`

### Does not work:

For all the `cacheable` methods defined at `CacheableRepository`. It seems that the `CacheConfig` annotation on `SomeObjectRepo` does not effect the `CacheableRepository`.

### My question:

Why the annotation does not work? Is there a workaround to get this structure to work?

Thanks,
Oak

Answer (score 3):

Yup, that's pretty much what Ollie and I found out when we tried to support that kind of scenario.

I would advise you to create an issue in the spring data project to request that feature.

Comment: Thanks for replying, My thoughts is that it is solvable via AOP. But i cannot think of the reason why it does not work. Maybe you can point it to me?

Comment: My best guess is that the `@CacheConfig` annotation is not read on the proxy interface. It's something to fix in the core. If you want a generic Spring Data repository caching solution, please consider creating an issue there and we'll work on a standard solution.

Comment: Thanks for the info :)

Comment: @oak Do you have any updates on this? Is it achievable after almost 8 years? 

Comment: @birca123, left this project a while ago, so I do not have any new information regarding it, but if you have/know about a solution please write :-)

Answer (score 0):

By using [`CacheResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/CacheResolver.html) shown below, the cache name can be determined based on the target repository's name, whose method was executed.

The configuration used to define the default `CacheResolver`:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CacheConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport {

  @Lazy private final CacheManager cacheManager;

  @Override
  public CacheResolver cacheResolver() {
    return new CustomCacheResolver(this.cacheManager);
  }

  public static class CustomCacheResolver extends SimpleCacheResolver {

    protected CustomCacheResolver(CacheManager cacheManager) {
      super(cacheManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected Collection<String> getCacheNames(CacheOperationInvocationContext<?> context) {
      return List.of(context.getTarget().getClass().getInterfaces()[0].getSimpleName());
    }
  }
}
```

With this solution, there is no need to specify cache names, since all cacheable methods are cached under the `SomeObjectRepo` cache name.

Note: To cache class methods, additional logic should be added to `getCacheNames`, otherwise it would not work.